# Finding the minimum value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so this table is concerning a charity. It has three tables. 1)donor 2) gift
and 3) year

I have to find the minimum value in the year 2000 displaying the first and last name of the donors. I am able to display the minimum amount for the year 2000, however the name of the donor is not right. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DONOR.DONOR_LNAME, DONOR.DONOR_FNAME, MIN( GIFT.AMOUNT ) 
FROM DONOR
JOIN GIFT ON DONOR.DONOR_NO = GIFT.DONOR_NO
WHERE YEAR_NUM =2000
HAVING MIN( GIFT.AMOUNT ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Please help

Donor table

[image]

Gift table

[image]

Comment: Please post your table structure, without which an exact answer may not be possible.

Comment: I just added screenshots. I also cannot add the year table because Im a new user.  I'm not sure but I dont think we need it since year is already in the gift table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.DONOR_FNAME AS first_name,
       t1.DONOR_LNAME AS last_name,
       t2.AMOUNT AS min_donation
FROM DONOR t1
INNER JOIN GIFT t2
    ON t1.DONOR_NO = t2.DONOR_NO
WHERE t2.YEAR_NUM = 2000 AND
      t2.AMOUNT = (SELECT MIN(AMOUNT) FROM GIFT WHERE YEAR_NUM = 2000 GROUP BY YEAR_NUM)
```

Comment: thanks alot. I was also wondering what the difference is between inner join and join?

Comment: `JOIN` usually defaults to meaning `INNER JOIN` in most RDBMS, if you have an `ON` clause.

Comment: Im just one point short of making my vote count. When I do I will make sure to upvote your post. Thanks again

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen +1 from me

Comment: @user5400828 Thanks I also hope your vote will count.

Answer (score 0):

Add Group by to your query, but not sure about the limit thing...

```
SELECT DONOR.DONOR_LNAME, DONOR.DONOR_FNAME, MIN( GIFT.AMOUNT) AS MinAmount
FROM DONOR
JOIN GIFT ON DONOR.DONOR_NO = GIFT.DONOR_NO
WHERE YEAR_NUM =2000
GROUP BY DONOR.DONOR_LNAME, DONOR.DONOR_FNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the table structures, you should try following Query.

```
SELECT DONOR.DONOR_NO, DONOR.DONOR_LNAME, DONOR.DONOR_FNAME, GIFT.AMOUNT
FROM DONOR INNER JOIN GIFT ON DONOR.DONOR_NO = GIFT.DONOR_NO
WHERE GIFT.YEAR_NUM =2000
HAVING MIN(GIFT.AMOUNT)
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: This won't fly because you are selecting columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (and also are not aggregates).

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need the lowest amount in the year 2000. This query gives me all the donations made in the year 2000

Comment: @user5400828 Fixed it.

Comment: This query still has problems.  I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My internet connection was lost, so couldn't post the solution. Now I've fixed it.